# Is volatile in C safe/good enough to signal another thread to stop itself when there is no shared data?

Tags: c

There are many resources that explain why using volatile alone is not enough for most multi threading applications.

However, is it good enough for simply signalling a thread to exit from another thread?
In the example below, the main thread starts a second thread and, after some time, it wants to stop it. There is no shared data between the threads and also no return code necessary from the thread, the thread is basically just used as a keep alive trigger for an attached hardware.

Example (thread_create and thread_join omitted for brevity, they are basically a wrapper around pthread_create and pthread_join or the Windows equivalent):

```c
typedef struct {
    volatile bool keepRunning;
} ThreadContext;

static void thread(void *arg) {
  ThreadContext *context = (ThreadContext *)arg;
  while (context->keepRunning) {
    // do some fast operation
    // ...
    // then sleep before next iteration
    msleep(100);
  }
}

static int startThread(ThreadContext *context) {
  context->keepRunning = true;
  return thread_create(thread, context);
}

static void stopThread(ThreadContext *context) {
  context->keepRunning = false;
  thread_join();
}

static int main() {
  ThreadContext context;
  startThread(&context);
  msleep(10000);
  stopThread(&context);
}
```

EDIT: I have to keep Windows compatibility and cross compile to a few ancient toolchains, so C11 with `stdatomic.h` is out of the picture. If there is a way to use regular condition variables on Windows, this might be a way I could try to check if all my targets support them.

EDIT2: Also, in this scenario I don't care about the precise order of events, the thread should only stop eventually (after at most a few iterations) and not wait forever on the join, but it does not have to stop immediately after setting the flag, i.e. it does no harm if the thread does another few iterations.

Comment: Look at pthread_cancel() and pthread_setcancelstate().

Comment: Ah sorry, messed it up while reducing the code to a simple example. The `volatile` is part of the context.

Comment: It should work but in theory it's undefined behavior. Why not make the variable `_Atomic`  and do a relaxed store?

Comment: @PSkocik because I don't have `_Atomic` support

Answer (score 0):

On most sane architectures and with most sane compilers accessing a variable `volatile bool` will work. It is however not guaranteed by the standard.

The POSIX standard guarantees safe access to `volatile sig_atomic_t` type in asynchronous interrupts. To be safe use `volatile sig_atomic_t`. Or just use `pthread_cond`.

```
typedef struct {
    volatile sig_atomic_t keepRunning;
} ThreadContext;
```

In C11 there is a way to check if accessing `bool` is atomic and safe from interrupt, you should if `ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE` is defined in `stdatomic.h`.

Some references: [C11 draft 5.1.2.3p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5) and [posix signal.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

Comment: But is "safe in interrupts" guaranteed to be the same as "safe in multithreading"?  I can imagine implementations where the two might be different

Comment: I don't really need it to be atomic and safe. I should just be able to observe a change of the value to 0 eventually (or from 0 to some other value if this makes a difference).

Comment: If you access "something" that is not atomic and "safe", then the value of that "something" becomes unspecified, according to the standard.

Comment: @NateEldredge "Safe in interrupt" means, between a signal handler and other thread(s). On POSIX the signal handler is executed in arbitrary chosen thread. From that I conclude that "safe in interrupt" must also mean "safe in multithreading". Practically, `sig_atomic_t` is accessed in one instruction. So you would have to have an architecture, when two threads are running on different CPUs and one CPU is able to observe the state of a variable mid-execution of an instruction on another CPU. Such architecture.. would be bad.

Comment: I guess I was picturing an implementation where signal handlers were wrapped with code that made all their writes visible to the main program and to other threads, but where a plain ordinary memory write, even to a `volatile` variable, didn't have that effect.  I'm not worrying about the worker thread seeing some "intermediate" value of the flag, but about whether it will ever see the change at all.

Comment: Just found http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_21.html#SEC364 which basically says that `sig_atomic_t` is not needed if a simple flag change is to be observed, which is the case in my example (and that types smaller or equal in size to `int` are basically always atomic anyways).

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: What exactly? Small types are atomic: `In practice, you can assume that int and other integer types no longer than int are atomic` and the simple flag change is described in the paragraph I linked.